# Unable to open encrypted(password protected) zip file in Python

Tags: python, zip

I have written small code in python to unzip the encrypted(password protected) file but while doing unzip to password protected code it is executing without error but it isn't doing unzip the file.

Any help will be appreciable.

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('/Users/xxxx/Documents/Project/xxxx/pythonPractice/input/my_zip_file.zip', "r")
try:
    z.extractall(path='/Users/xxxx/Documents/Project/xxxx/pythonPractice/output/myunzipfile.txt',pwd=bytes('xxxxxx').encode('utf-8'))
except IOError as e:
    print('Error' + str(e))
    #pass
z.close()
```

Comment: Hmm, is this python 2? `bytes(...).encode()` doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: In that case `bytes(...).encode` is an error. Which doesn't match your description that this executes without error. Can we see your *real* code?

Comment: Saying "it isn't doing unzip the file" doesn't tell us much.  What _does_ happen?  Do you get the exception message?  Also, why are you using a filename for the `path` argument?  It should be a _directory_, not a filename.

Comment: @JohnGordon Basically code is not able to unzip the file and running without error. As per the syntax  given by zipfile.py "def extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None): " and I'm follow the same. I would like to inform I ran without giving path variable then also it is not able to unzip the file.